# Facing issue while sending SMS with Twilio Copilot

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to work on Twilio Copilot. I have created the SID.I have also assigned a UK number .I need to send messages to UK, US and South africa for now.

I am currently facing problem is sending messages to US. Do i need to assign a seperate US number for it to work (Same for Other Countries)?

I am using C# Twilio 4.7.2 library.

Comment: UK numbers on Twilio support international sms, so you should be fine there. What error are you getting?

Comment: In twilio console it is giving me this Error : (Error: 21612) The &#039;To&#039; phone number is not currently reachable via SMS. You have attempted to send to a number that is not currently reachable via Twilio SMS. If the number provided is a properly formatted E.164, it is most likely that Twilio does not yet have service with the carrier you are trying to reach. We have logged the carrier you are attempting to reach and will monitor these failures when adding new carriers.

But i have sent the number in correct format +190xxxxxxxx. Don't know what i am doing wrong

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

My guess is that you have a UK landline number. That is a number that currently supports voice and messaging and starts +441, +442 or +443.

UK landline numbers cannot currently send international SMS.

If you still want to use a UK number to send international messages, you can get a UK mobile number, which will start +447, though currently these numbers do not support incoming voice calls.

Best practice for sending international messages is to try to use a local number to send them. When you are using Copilot it will automatically geomatch the best number to the location you are sending to.

Comment: Yes, i am using a number starting with +447. For now i only ave to send SMS i tried to send SMS on two different US numbers it failed for one and was undelivered for the second one. But its working fine if i send SMS in UK.

Comment: I just saw your comment on the question as well. It looks like you're doing the right thing right now, but there's trouble with the number you're trying to send to. I'd get in touch with [Twilio support](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact) and supply them with the message SIDs of the failed messages and they can follow up.